# mass label text after Scroll table view

Tags: objective-c, three20

I have a table like this:

[image: before drag table]

after several time drag to scroll table view it likes:

[image: after drag table several times]

I subclassed TTTableMessageItemCell and in subclassing class I added this:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    _timeLabel.text = nil;
    _timeLabel = nil;
    self.commentTime = nil;
}
```

but not work...
what's wrong?

---

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {


    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.backgroundColor = TTSTYLEVAR(tableCellColor1);


    CGSize userNameSize = [self.username sizeWithFont:TTSTYLEVAR(mySubtextFont)];


    if (self.username != nil && self.username.length){

        self.userNameLabel.text = self.username;


        self.userNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.imageView2.right + 5.f, self.imageView2.top, userNameSize.width, userNameSize.height);
    }else{
        self.userNameLabel.frame = CGRectZero;

    }


self.titleLabel.width, captionSize.height);
    if (self.typeMessage != nil && self.typeMessage.length){

        self.typeMessageLabel.text = self.typeMessage;

        self.typeMessageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.imageView2.right + userNameSize.width + 5.f, kTableCellSmallMargin, self.contentView.width - self.imageView2.right - userNameSize.height - 5.f, userNameSize.height);
    }else{
        self.typeMessageLabel.frame = CGRectZero;
    }
}


- (UILabel*)userNameLabel{
    if (self.username != nil && self.username.length) {
        _userNameLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease] ;
        _userNameLabel.tag = 107;
        _userNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


        _userNameLabel.font = TTSTYLEVAR(mySubtextFont);
        _userNameLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeLeft;
        //        _typeMessageLabel.enabled = NO;
        //        [_typeMessageLabel sizeToFit];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_userNameLabel];
        _userNameLabel =  (UILabel *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:107];
    }
    return _userNameLabel;
}

- (UILabel*)typeMessageLabel{
    if (self.typeMessage != nil && self.typeMessage.length) {
        _typeMessageLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease] ;
        _typeMessageLabel.tag = 105;
        _typeMessageLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


        _typeMessageLabel.font = TTSTYLEVAR(mySubtextFont);
        _typeMessageLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeLeft;
//        _typeMessageLabel.enabled = NO;
//        [_typeMessageLabel sizeToFit];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_typeMessageLabel];
        _typeMessageLabel =  (UILabel *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:105];
    }
    return _typeMessageLabel;
}
```

Comment: Post any code you have where you are creating a text label for the cell.

Comment: Add the code for where you create the label, not adjust it. Specifically, add the code where you addSubview

Comment: I've already added, you can scroll down the added code and you will see the creating label code "userNameLabel" and "typeMessageLabel"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `userNameLabel` and `typeMessageLabel` methods, you are creating a new label every time it is called, adding it to the cell's `contentView`, and you are not removing the old one ever.

You need to make your cell subclass have iVars and create the labels only once, then just set the text when rendering the cell

```
- (UILabel*)userNameLabel{
    if (!_userNameLabel) {
        _userNameLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
        _userNameLabel.tag = 107;
        _userNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _userNameLabel.font = TTSTYLEVAR(mySubtextFont);
        _userNameLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeLeft;
        [self.contentView addSubview:_userNameLabel];
    }
    return _userNameLabel;
}

- (UILabel*)typeMessageLabel{
    if (!_typeMessageLabel) {
        _typeMessageLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease] ;
        _typeMessageLabel.tag = 105;
        _typeMessageLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];    
        _typeMessageLabel.font = TTSTYLEVAR(mySubtextFont);
        _typeMessageLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeLeft;
        [self.contentView addSubview:_typeMessageLabel];
    }
    return _typeMessageLabel;
}
```

Then, set your cell's object in the correct place: the `setObject:` method, not the `layoutSubviews` method. The `layoutSubviews` method can be called multiple times per draw, and should only have the bare minimum positioning logic you need to layout the cells. Setting text, creating items and other high-cost functions should be down in `setObject`.

```
- (void)setObject:(id)object {
    [super setObject:object];
    …
    (Do your other content-related setup here, not in layoutSubviews)
    …
    if ([self.username length])
        _userNameLabel.text = self.username;
    if ([self.typeMessage length])
        _typeMessageLabel.text = self.typeMessage;
}
```

Then in the `prepareForReuse` method, you set the text of these labels to be nil.